# PCB quick question

Tags: pcb

I'm getting close to pulling the trigger on ordering PCB etc. for a project, and I'm looking at about a dozen DIP sockets on the board.
The small 7-segment displays I'm looking at have pretty spendy sockets (if I spec'd out right, >$5 each!!), so I was looking at getting something like a 40-pin SIP strip for $2 and change, then cutting them down into a series of strips I can just stuff and solder.
Would there be any downside if I just used SIP strip everywhere instead of getting proper sockets? (when it comes to installing, I would stick a random part that fits to 'gauge' the strips in vertically long enough to tack-solder etc.)

Comment: You're likely comparing to some obscure and specialized socket rather than a generic low cost solution for your actual problem which should sell at several per dollar.  Are you aware of the difference between machine pin and simpler sockets, and which is suitable for your usage pattern?  Manual modification can work but beware you'll loose a pin at each cut...

Comment: Vertical alignment.  Some components, especially displays, have less compliant pins.  A little tilt here and there gets pretty aggravating after a while.  If this is not a high-reliability or harsh environment, you probably do not need screw-machined contacts in the socket.

Comment: If cost is the prevailing factor, why use sockets at all? Direct soldering of components is less expensive.

Comment: don't forget that multiple digit 7-segnent readouts are available .... they would require less pins

Comment: Personally, I see little to no reason to use sockets. However, that is not what you asked. And you may have your reasons, I guess.

Comment: I can't help but wonder, why are you using sockets?